# Traces or marks? Which one is better and why?

Tags: meaning, phrases

> It was in the Caribbean, on the island of Nevis, that Nelson met and married Fanny Nisbet, and the island still bears  traces / marks of the young captain’s presence.

Traces or marks? Which one is better and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could practically flip a coin, since they both fit the sentence equally well, although with slight differences in nuance.

*Traces* suggests the remnants are faint and greatly diminished by time or weather.

> Although unopened for many centuries ago, when the tomb was first opened the archaeologists still detected *traces* of the incense that must have been burning when it was sealed.

*Marks* suggests the remnants were originally made by some kind of action, often deliberate action.

> The ancient mine still bears the *marks* of the worker's picks on the walls, and even occasional initials, names, or crude drawings.

One is more passive, the other more active.  Both are fine -- it just depends what you want to say.